# rviz fails to build

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy, osx, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried to build Groovy on OSX (10.8) and rviz fails. I installed Ogre with homebrew, but half way through building rviz there are error messages about Ogre.

All of the other packages compile fine until rviz and then rviz dies here:

```
==> make -j2 in '/Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/build_isolated/rviz'
[  0%] [  0%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/frame_position_tracking_view_controller.cpp.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/image/image_display_base.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/loading_dialog.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/mesh_loader.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/new_object_dialog.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/apply_visibility_bits.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/arrow.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/axes.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/billboard_line.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/camera_base.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/grid.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/initialization.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/movable_text.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/object.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/ogre_logging.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/ogre_render_queue_clearer.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/orthographic.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/point_cloud.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/qt_ogre_render_window.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/render_system.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/render_widget.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/shape.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/ogre_helpers/stl_loader.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/panel.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/panel_dock_widget.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/panel_factory.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/bool_property.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/color_editor.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/color_property.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/combo_box.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/display_visibility_property.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/display_group_visibility_property.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/editable_combo_box.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/editable_enum_property.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/enum_property.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/float_edit.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/float_property.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/int_property.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/line_edit_with_button.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/parse_color.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/property.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/property_tree_delegate.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/property_tree_model.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/property_tree_widget.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/property_tree_with_help.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/quaternion_property.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/ros_topic_property.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/splitter_handle.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/status_list.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/status_property.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/string_property.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/tf_frame_property.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/vector_property.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/render_panel.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/robot/robot_link.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/robot/robot.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/src/rviz/src/rviz/robot/robot_link.cpp:45:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/urdf_interface/model.h:38:2: warning: "Please Use #include <urdf_model/model.h>" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Please Use #include <urdf_model/model.h>"
 ^
In file included from /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/src/rviz/src/rviz/robot/robot_link.cpp:46:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/urdf_interface/link.h:38:2: warning: "Please Use #include <urdf_model/link.h>" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Please Use #include <urdf_model/link.h>"
 ^
In file included from /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/src/rviz/src/rviz/robot/robot.cpp:39:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/urdf_interface/model.h:38:2: warning: "Please Use #include <urdf_model/model.h>" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Please Use #include <urdf_model/model.h>"
 ^
2 warnings generated.
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/robot/tf_link_updater.cpp.o
1 warning generated.
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/scaled_image_widget.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/screenshot_dialog.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/selection_panel.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/selection/selection_handler.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/selection/selection_manager.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/splash_screen.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/time_panel.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/tool.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/tool_manager.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/uniform_string_stream.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/view_controller.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/view_manager.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/views_panel.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualization_frame.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualization_manager.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/visualizer_app.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/wait_for_master_dialog.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/widget_geometry_change_detector.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/tool_properties_panel.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/yaml_config_reader.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/yaml_config_writer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/__/__/build/env_config.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_display_context.cxx.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_display_group.cxx.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_display.cxx.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_displays_panel.cxx.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_failed_panel.cxx.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_frame_manager.cxx.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_frame_position_tracking_view_controller.cxx.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_help_panel.cxx.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/image/moc_image_display_base.cxx.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_loading_dialog.cxx.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_message_filter_display.cxx.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_new_object_dialog.cxx.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_panel_dock_widget.cxx.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_panel.cxx.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_bool_property.cxx.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_color_editor.cxx.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_color_property.cxx.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_combo_box.cxx.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_display_visibility_property.cxx.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_display_group_visibility_property.cxx.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_editable_combo_box.cxx.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_editable_enum_property.cxx.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_enum_property.cxx.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_float_edit.cxx.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_float_property.cxx.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_int_property.cxx.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_line_edit_with_button.cxx.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_property.cxx.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_property_tree_delegate.cxx.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_property_tree_model.cxx.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_property_tree_widget.cxx.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_property_tree_with_help.cxx.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_quaternion_property.cxx.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_ros_topic_property.cxx.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_splitter_handle.cxx.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_status_list.cxx.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_status_property.cxx.o
[ 33%] [ 33%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_string_property.cxx.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_tf_frame_property.cxx.o
[ 33%] [ 34%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/properties/moc_vector_property.cxx.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_render_panel.cxx.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/robot/moc_robot_link.cxx.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_scaled_image_widget.cxx.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_screenshot_dialog.cxx.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/selection/moc_selection_manager.cxx.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_splash_screen.cxx.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_time_panel.cxx.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_tool_manager.cxx.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_tool.cxx.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_view_controller.cxx.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_view_manager.cxx.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_views_panel.cxx.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_visualization_frame.cxx.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_visualization_manager.cxx.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_visualizer_app.cxx.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_wait_for_master_dialog.cxx.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_widget_geometry_change_detector.cxx.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_selection_panel.cxx.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_tool_properties_panel.cxx.o
Linking CXX shared library /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.dylib
[ 61%] Built target rviz
[ 61%] Generating view_controllers/moc_fps_view_controller.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target executable
[ 61%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/executable.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 61%] Generating moc_axes_display.cxx
[ 61%] Generating moc_camera_display.cxx
[ 61%] Generating moc_depth_cloud_display.cxx
Linking CXX executable /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/rviz
[ 62%] Generating moc_grid_cells_display.cxx
[ 62%] Built target executable
[ 62%] Generating moc_image_view.cxx
[ 62%] Generating moc_grid_display.cxx
[ 62%] Generating moc_image_display.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target rviz_image_view
[ 62%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o
[ 62%] Generating moc_interactive_marker_display.cxx
[ 63%] Generating interactive_markers/moc_integer_action.cxx
[ 63%] Generating interactive_markers/moc_interactive_marker.cxx
[ 63%] Generating moc_laser_scan_display.cxx
[ 64%] Generating moc_map_display.cxx
[ 64%] Generating moc_marker_display.cxx
[ 64%] Generating moc_marker_array_display.cxx
[ 64%] Generating moc_odometry_display.cxx
[ 65%] Generating moc_path_display.cxx
[ 65%] Generating moc_point_cloud_common.cxx
[ 65%] Generating moc_point_cloud_display.cxx
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 67%] Generating moc_point_cloud_transformer.cxx
[ 67%] Generating moc_point_cloud_transformers.cxx
[ 67%] Generating moc_point_cloud2_display.cxx
[ 67%] Generating moc_polygon_display.cxx
[ 68%] Generating moc_pose_array_display.cxx
[ 68%] Generating moc_pose_display.cxx
[ 68%] Generating moc_range_display.cxx
[ 69%] Generating moc_robot_model_display.cxx
[ 69%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/moc_image_view.cxx.o
[ 69%] Generating moc_tf_display.cxx
[ 69%] Generating tools/moc_goal_tool.cxx
[ 69%] Generating tools/moc_initial_pose_tool.cxx
[ 70%] Generating tools/moc_interaction_tool.cxx
[ 70%] Generating view_controllers/moc_orbit_view_controller.cxx
[ 70%] Generating view_controllers/moc_xy_orbit_view_controller.cxx
[ 71%] Generating view_controllers/moc_fixed_orientation_ortho_view_controller.cxx
Linking CXX executable /Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/image_view
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GetCurrentProcess", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SetFrontProcess", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_TransformProcessType", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Quaternion::IDENTITY", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Rectangle2D::setCorners(float, float, float, float, bool)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Rectangle2D::Rectangle2D(bool, Ogre::HardwareBuffer::Usage)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned long, char const*, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
      Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::Resource>::destroy() in image_view.cpp.o
      Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::Material>::destroy() in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton()", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::SimpleRenderable::setMaterial(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::SimpleRenderable::setBoundingBox(Ogre::AxisAlignedBox const&)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::TextureUnitState::setTextureName(std::string const&, Ogre::TextureType)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::TextureUnitState::setTextureFiltering(Ogre::TextureFilterOptions)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Pass::setDepthWriteEnabled(bool)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Pass::createTextureUnitState()", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Root::renderOneFrame()", referenced from:
      ImageView::onTimer() in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Root::createSceneManager(unsigned short, std::string const&)", referenced from:
      ImageView::ImageView(QWidget*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_SCALE", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Vector3::ZERO", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Material::getTechnique(unsigned short)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Material::setCullingMode(Ogre::CullingMode)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Technique::setLightingEnabled(bool)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
  "Ogre::Technique::getPass(unsigned short)", referenced from:
      ImageView::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in image_view.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/image_view] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Scanning dependencies of target default_plugin
[ 71%] [ 71%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/camera_display.cpp.o
Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/axes_display.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/depth_cloud_display.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/grid_cells_display.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/grid_display.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/image_display.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/interactive_marker_display.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/interactive_markers/integer_action.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/interactive_markers/interactive_marker_control.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/interactive_markers/interactive_marker.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/laser_scan_display.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/map_display.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/marker_array_display.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/marker_display.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/arrow_marker.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/line_list_marker.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/line_strip_marker.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/marker_base.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/marker_selection_handler.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/mesh_resource_marker.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/points_marker.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/shape_marker.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/text_view_facing_marker.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/markers/triangle_list_marker.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/odometry_display.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/path_display.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/point_cloud2_display.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/point_cloud_common.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/point_cloud_display.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/point_cloud_transformers.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/polygon_display.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/pose_array_display.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/pose_display.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/range_display.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/robot_model_display.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/tf_display.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/tools/measure_tool.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/tools/move_tool.cpp.o
/Users/kevin/tmp/groovy2/src/rviz/src/rviz/default_plugin/tools/measure_tool.cpp:15:10: fatal error: 'OgreSceneNode.h' file not found
#include <OgreSceneNode.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/tools/measure_tool.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [src/rviz/default_plugin/CMakeFiles/default_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'rviz': 
  Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env_cached.sh make -j2' returned non-zero exit status 2
Command failed, exiting.
[kevin@tardis groovy2]$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52399/rviz-fails-to-build/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-16**:
I am working on a set of patches, there will be one to get it building soon, but this one is a problem still:https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have compiled patches and solutions to problems with rviz here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#rviz

Including the solution to this one, which is in the pull request located here:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/563

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-16**:
Thanks ... I got rviz compiled, now I am working on fixing rqt_rviz

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-16**:
There is a bug in rqt where the menu bar doesn't show on mac too.  I'll get around to that one ASAP

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-24**:
Sorry, no ... I have a problem of not always working linearly :). I couldn't get rqt_viz working so I deleted the package and moved on to the rosbuild packages. The navigation stuff relied on pcl, so I had to get pcl 1.7 working [done], but now I am hung up on another package.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-24**:
Sorry, stupid short comments .... I will try to circle back to rqt_rvis later and see what I can do. I want to try and file some bug tickets for @WilliamWoodall on some of my other fixes first though, when I get a chance.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-24**:
Sorry ... I used the unstable pcl 1.7. I posted the changes needed on the OSX-SIG mailing list. I don't think willow garage is officially interested the unstable pcl. Also, I have not been able to completely test everything, basically I got everything to compile and be happy.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-24**:
I will have more time this weekend to test things better.